# count number of cells that meet certain criteria between two other cells with certain criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking for a way to count the number of cells meeting a specific criteria that are located between two other cells.  For example:

```
  A                B      C       D      E
151867377   01:03.5 63500   1325    ARFC
151867611   01:03.5 63734   1325    BC25
151867611   01:03.5 63734   1325    M25T
151867613   01:03.5 63736   1325    ShowComms 1325 Track classified as HOSTILE. 
151868763   01:04.7 64886   1325    BC25
151868763   01:04.7 64886   1325    M25T
151868765   01:04.7 64888   1325    ShowComms 1325 Track classified as HOSTILE. 
151870850   01:06.8 66973   1325    AFOK
151870852   01:06.8 66975   1325    KR03
151872490   01:08.5 68613   1325    BC25
```

In column E, I am looking for the number of cells that start with `B` between the `ARFC` and the `KR03` cells.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use something like this:

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(E2,MATCH(H2,E2:E11,0)-1,0,MATCH(H3,INDEX(E2:E11,MATCH(H2,E2:E11,0)):E11,0)),"B*")
```

I'm using `OFFSET` here to define the range in which you will count the cells.

The first `MATCH` indicates where the range starts, the second match indicates where it ends.

The second match uses `INDEX` and `MATCH` to make sure that the 'ending' cell is not before the 'starting' cell.

`B*` is for matching cells beginning with `B`.

[image]